# Populating an array with JLabels

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, jlabel

I have this snippet of my code with my JLabels and JTextFields. I was wondering if - to save space - I could somehow add my JLabels and/or JTextFields to an array? I have many more JLabels and JTextFields than these below.

```
     JLabel lblVundet = new JLabel("Won");
     lblVundet.setBounds(5, 10, 50, 16);
     mainframe.add(lblVundet);

     JLabel lblUafgjort = new JLabel("Draw");
     lblUafgjort.setBounds(5, 55, 60, 16);
     mainframe.add(lblUafgjort);

     JLabel lblTabt = new JLabel("Lost");
     lblTabt.setBounds(5, 100, 60, 16);
     mainframe.add(lblTabt);


     txtFieldWon = new JTextField();
     txtFieldWon.setBounds(168, 4, 134, 28);
     mainframe.add(txtFieldWon);
     txtFieldWon.setColumns(10);

     txtFieldDraw = new JTextField();
     txtFieldDraw.setBounds(168, 49, 134, 28);
     mainframe.add(txtFieldDraw);
     txtFieldDraw.setColumns(10);

     txtFieldLost = new JTextField();
     txtFieldLost.setBounds(168, 94, 134, 28);
     mainframe.add(txtFieldLost);
     txtFieldLost.setColumns(10);
```

Comment: And what do you want to do with that array? If you just want to reduce the code, then you can create methods like `createLabel(String text, int yCoord, JPanel panel)` or `createTextField(int yCoord, JPanel panel)` and call them accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just create for loop and reduce the redundancy in your code. It would be good if you seperate below code in two different method and call them to reduce duplication.

If you really need (although i don't see any need) you could store the labels/fields into array since you have number's of labels and field handy.

```
String labels[] = {"Won", "Draw", "Lost"};
JLabel label;
for (int i =0; i<labels.length; i++) {
    label = new JLabel(labels[i]);
    label.setBounds(5, 10 + (i * 45), 50, 16);
    mainframe.add(label);
}

JTextField jTextField;
int txtFieldCount = 3;
for (int i=0 ;i<txtFieldCount; i++) {
   jTextField = new JTextField();
   jTextField.setBounds(168, 4 + (i * 45), 134, 28);
   mainframe.add(jTextField);
   jTextField.setColumns(10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to store those in an array, I would suggest to use ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<JLabel> allJLabels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
ArrayList<JTextField> allJTextFields = new ArrayList<JTextFields>();
```

If that's what you want. This is only saving space if for all labels/textfields you have the same values. But I think all labels won't have the same text.
For this purpose I would create your own method:

```
private JLabel createLabel(String text, int b1, int b2, int b3, int b4)
{
    JLabel l = new JLabel(text);
    l.setBounds(b1, b2, b3, b4);
    return l;
}
```

Then it's just one line:

```
allJLabels.add(createLabel("Won", 5, 10, 50, 16));
```

Afterwards you add them to the mainframe (in the order you added the items):

```
for(int i = 0; i < allJLabels.size(); ++i)
{
    mainframe.add(allJLabels.get(i));
}
```